# How to get the size of the owning window?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to set the width and height of a Window to the width and height of its owner window in XAML. How do I do that? Does it help if the owner window is the MainWindow?

```
<Window Width="???" Height="???"/>
```

Comment: Window.Size = new Size(width, height);

Comment: @Anton: What is `width` and `height`? And how is that XAML?

Comment: Where is you need set size in xaml or in .cs?<br>

Comment: @Anton: I want to set the width and height of a Window to the width and height of its owner in XAML.

Comment: You can't bind from XAML to parent window.

Comment: @Anton: What if the parent window is the MainWindow?

Comment: Please explain the reason for the downvote so that I can improve my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously the code I think you require, if you are creating a **TestWindow** from main window. You can directly set it's width and height from using the `this.Width` and `this.Height` keywords.

```
var window = new TestWindow();
window.Width = this.Width;
window.Height = this.Height;
window.Show();
```

If you want to set the TestWindow Width and height from its constructor, then do like below in TestWindow  constructor:

```
foreach(var window in Application.Current.Windows)
{
    if (window is MainWindow)
    {
            this.Width = ((Window)window).Width;
            this.Height = ((Window)window).Height;

    }
}
```

Comment: Use **DataBinding**

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Bind it to some property using Two-way binding and it should do the trick. `Width="{Binding Path=xExt, Mode=TwoWay}"`

Comment: Okay, so there is no internal mechanism. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can do it by XAML only like:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListBoxTest" x:Class="ListBoxTest.ChildWindows"
        Title="ChildWindows" Height="{Binding ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay}">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindow/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <!--here whatever you want to do...-->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You have to bind height and width with the actual width and height of MainWindows but before that you have to set DataContext for ChildWindws that is MainWindows, like:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindow/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Here parent windows is MainWindows.

Comment: Unfortunately I am already using a different DataContext because I am doing MVVM.